# Can't get form_state['values'] from a form on a custom checkout pane

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I created a custom checkout pane with Drupal Commerce so if a user checkouts as anonymous they can create an account on the checkout completion page.  The problem is that when in my form's submit function the form_state values are not passed and I get an undefined index error.
Here is the code for the checkout form:

```
function commerce_checkout_complete_registration_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {

      $form['new_email'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Email'),
        '#element_validate' => array('_validate_the_email'),
      );

      $form['pass'] = array(
        '#type' => 'password_confirm',
      );

      $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Register'),
        '#submit' => array('commerce_checkout_complete_registration_pane_checkout_form_submit'),
      );

      global $user;
      if($user->uid == 0){
        return $form;
      }

    }
```

And here is the submit function:

```
function commerce_checkout_complete_registration_pane_checkout_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  dpm($form_state);
  $email_address = $form_state['values']['new_email'];
  syslog(1, $email_address . 'TEST');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "commerce_checkout_complete_registration_pane_checkout_form" needed to have the $form variable passed as a reference, &$form.